# How can I get the image in the img file in solution

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have 2 folders, img and css. I have a section in css where I have added a background image. But i can't access the img folder from the css folder. Thanks in advance.

```
height: 100%;
background: #e74c3c url('img/lib2.jpg') 50% 50%;
background-size: cover;
```

**screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: `../img/lib2.jpg` - paths are relative the the CSS file not the HTML.

Comment: `../` used for coming out from one level. So you have to used `background: #e74c3c url('../img/lib2.jpg') 50% 50%;`

Comment: This is indeed a duplicate question, but this one at least includes a screenshot to illustrate some stuff :)